# Applet unable to create socket connection on localhost

Tags: java, security, networking, same-origin-policy

I have a java applet, which once loaded on the users machine (through the webpage), I want it to create a server socket and socket on the local machine on which it is being viewed. Is this not allowed ?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).  I suspect that while the **first** (1) 2 answers provided have a 'grain of truth' to them, that they have both got it slightly wrong.  Give me some code to play with, & I'll test my theories.  1) Tom's answer seems correct.

Answer (score 4):

Java applets **can** open `Socket`s to their *same-origin* host. For around a decade, they can also open `ServerSocket`s (the OS will typically restrict listening ports under 1024) and accept connections only from the *same-origin* host. In addition `crossdomain.xml` may loosen restrictions, from 6u10.

Of note for localhost: your machines outward facing IP address(es) is not the same as 127.0.0.1, code loaded from `file` URLs do not match network connections to 127.0.0.1 (although sometimes the empty string can be interpreted as localhost; also note what your classpath might be pointing (say `.`) may be loaded in priority to network loaded code depending upon exactly what you are doing but not normally through a browser) and JavaScript only has same-origin permissions to connect to the same host only on the same port as the code was downloaded from.

Comment: Hawtin I also tried using my outward facing IP address(found using whatismyipaddress.com) but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

if you digitally sign your applet, it can run "unrestricted" http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html apparently (same with java webstart)